# MYSQL - Querying database where & is in cell

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with items in my MySQL database.

I am trying to query a row which contains "&". The column is a text value and contains the content "TV & Stands".

```
SELECT * FROM  `items` WHERE  `name` =  'TV & Stands' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This returns 0 results, even though "TV & Stands" is clearly within the name column. If I query an item name without the "&" character, it returns the correct value.

How would I query this data properly?

Comment: works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc7625/1

Comment: does the db really have **&** and not **&amp;** ??

Comment: @Dagon: yes, it that a security concern?

Comment: no i was just checking that you where searching for the right things - i see you picked an answer below so was the problem white space ?

Comment: @Dagon, yep that was it! One of those idiotic mistakes that took me too long to figure out. I guess I didn't have enough coffee in my system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `=` operator, it will match both value and length. May be your string contains some additional space before/after the string which is not visible in normal. So try `LIKE` operator instate.

```
SELECT * FROM  `items` WHERE  `name` LIKE '%TV & Stands%'
```

Answer (score 2):

The *database* shouldn't have a problem with the ampersand, so this is a problem at the application layer.  You can get around it using `like`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `items`
WHERE `name` LIKE 'TV _ Stands'
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

Comment: I'm running the query in PHPMyAdmin, so it can't be at application level. I never had this issue before though.

Comment: @steeped PHPMyAdmin is an application

Comment: Yes, but PHPMyAdmin wouldn't break like this.